# MIPS Instruction Decoding

Tags: assembly, mips, disassembly, objdump, instruction-encoding

I'm trying to understand how to decode MIPS binary instructions.

I compiled a hello world program in C on a Debian MIPS system with gcc and objdump shows me that the first instruction in the .text section is:

`600:   03e00025    move    zero,ra`

I don't understand how it determines that this is the `MOVE` instruction.

`03e00025` is `00000011111000000000000000100101` in binary. If I understand correctly the first 6 bits here are the opcode, which in this case is all 0, meaning it's an R-type instruction, so we have to look at the last 6 bits, which is `100101`. Looking at the [MIPS Instruction Set Manual](https://www.mips.com/products/architectures/mips32-2/) it looks like this should be the `OR` instruction. I can't even find `MOVE` in that manual.

Googling for this I found that apparently there are "pseudo" instructions in the assembly, and supposedly `move $t, $s` expands to `addiu $t, $s, 0`, but if I look in the manual `ADDIU` has opcode `001001`. Another result I found claims it translates to `ADD` but the last six bits of `ADD` should be `100000`, so that doesn't fit either.

What am I missing?

Comment: Yes that is encoded as `or $0, $ra, $0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MIPS machine code doesn't have a specific opcode for `move`, but for the convenience of humans, many assemblers support pseudo-instructions like `li`, `la`, and `move` that assemble to one or more real machine instructions.  `addiu` is a common one.

It would be totally correct for objdump to decode the instruction as `or $0, $ra, $0` (according to Jester) to show you how it's actually encoded.

For some purposes it makes sense for a disassembler to decode any of the commonly used ways to copy a register into a `move` mnemonic.  Adding or ORing an immediate `0`, or a zero from reading the `$zero` register, do nothing to the value so it's copied unchanged.

When reading the asm, you normally don't care whether it's `or`, `ori`, `addiu $0, $ra, 0`, or whatever.

---

Different assemblers might use different implementations for the `move` pseudo-instruction, or hand-written asm could use any of them.  I don't think there are any performance consequences either way.  So the details of which machine instruction is used to implement a `move` depends on the assembler.

---

I'm not sure what the point of a `move` with a destination of `$zero` is.  That would be a no-op, because `$zero` discards writes.  (It's the CPU-register equivalent of `/dev/zero`)

Comment: Oh wow, awesome answer! Now I get it :-) Thank you very much!

Comment: On the point of implementation choice for pseudoinstructions: some ISAs (e.g. RISC-V) define canonical encodings for pseudoinstr. like `nop` and `mov`. In complex microarchitectures this can enable simpler detection logic for e.g. zero-cycle register renaming because there's only a single encoding to detect. `nop`-like instr. can also be used to encode microarch. hints (e.g. branch prediction hints).